# How to fetch a file using nifi from a fileshare location?

Tags: azure-storage, apache-nifi

I am trying to fetch some files from a fileshare location in a azure storage account using NiFi. I tried the fetchFTP processor but it is not being able to connect to the url of the fileshare location . I tried putting the correct parameters, but I am getting an error.

> Failed to fetch file on remote host due to java.net.UknownHostException:

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment yet...

2 things:

- UnknownHostException strongly indicates that the entered hostname is wrong or cannot be resolved by the nifi host.
- Azure files in general does not work with FTP because it works on the SMB protocol or REST api. You could mount it directly on the nifi machines.[See here, how to mount azure files on a nifi machine. Has to be done on every node.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux) Once that works, you can use ListFiles and GetFile processors in nifi.

Comment: Thanks for the response ! I am new to azure as well as NiFi . So what can I do to fetch files from azure , what are the alternatives ?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Ya , I mounted the fileshare on my local machine where NiFi was installed . It worked .